# When did the term "second-party developer" stop being used to refer to the user?

Tags: terminology

I always believed that when it came to software for a platform the parties were referred to as such:

> First-party:  The owner/creator of the
>   platform
>
> Second-party: The user of the platform
>
> Third-party: A developer who is not
>   the first-party.

Now second-party seems to be used to refer to a developer owned/contracted by the owner/creator of the platform.  When did this change in terminology come about and do we solely refer to "user created software" as such?

Comment: You mean it's not first-party developers=democratic ones, second-party developers=communist ones, and third-party developers=everybody else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the notion goes back to commercial arrangements. The first and second parties are in a direct producer-purchaser relationship.  The third-party parties are those other than the first party that the second party is dealing with.  (Note that grammatical person doesn't quite fit, but it is a cute idea.  It works better if the first party is the customer and the second-party is the primary supplier.)

In this context, it is perhaps overloading too much on the term to say second-party developer.  The second-party might be an IT organization and have to do many activities to install and use the products and services of the first-party.  It might farm out a lot of that to third parties, too.

Perhaps the key thing is that the third party is generally not part of the (business) relationship between the first and second parties.

Answer (score 0):

I agree, I always assumed it was a pun or extension of standard English grammar: [first person](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-person_narrative), second person, and third person.

Answer (score 0):

A first party developer is either the hardware owner, a sub division or a company bought up by the hardware company. A second party developer is a company comissioned to make a game from a concept by a publisher, while a third party developer is independent and work on games by using dev kits and licencing, paying a fee to the hard ware maker.